# Select a different column from the row containing the max

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My query looks like this:

```
  SELECT     [ScriptName]
        ,[BranchName]
        ,AVG([XMLColumn].value('count(//data)', 'int'))
        ,MIN([XMLColumn].value('count(//data)', 'int'))
        ,MAX([XMLColumn].value('count(//data)', 'int'))
  FROM temp
  GROUP BY [BranchName], [ScriptName]
```

The table I'm querying is structured like this:

```
ScriptName | BranchName | XMLLog | Developer | Revision
```

Currently, my results query produces output like this:

```
ScriptName | BranchName | Average | Min | MAX
-------------------------------------------------
Script 1   | trunk      |  80     | 11  | 120
Script 2   | branch1    |  15     | 11  | 21
```

I want to add two columns to my results table: the developer from the row containing the minimum value and the developer from the row containing the maximum value. This would result in the output from the query looking like this:

```
ScriptName | BranchName | Average | Min | MAX  | DeveloperWhoCausedMinimum | DeveloperWhoCausedMaximum
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Script 1   | trunk      |  80     | 11  | 120  |      me                   |     The Boss
Script 2   | branch1    |  15     | 11  | 21   |      me                   |     The Boss
```

I am not sure where to start on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following uses window function to calculate the three values.  It then selects the entire row with the max value:

```
select t.*, avgval, minval, maxval
from (select t.*,
             avg([XMLColumn].value('count(//data)', 'int') over
                 (partition by BranchName, ScriptName) as avgval,
             min([XMLColumn].value('count(//data)', 'int') over
                 (partition by BranchName, ScriptName) as minval,
             max([XMLColumn].value('count(//data)', 'int') over
                 (partition by BranchName, ScriptName) as maxval
      from temp t
     ) t
where [XMLColumn].value('count(//data)', 'int') = maxval;
```

Note:  if multiple rows have the maximum value, you will get multiple rows out.  If you want only one, then use `row_number()` instead.

EDIT:

Oh, you changed the question to be one column from two different rows rather than two rows from one column.

Use the same idea but with aggregation:

```
select BranchName, ScriptName, minval, avgval, maxval,
       avg([XMLColumn].value('count(//data)', 'int') as avgval,
       min([XMLColumn].value('count(//data)', 'int') as minval,
       max([XMLColumn].value('count(//data)', 'int') as maxval,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then Developer end) as minDeveloper,
       max(case when seqnum = cnt then Developer end) as maxDeveloper
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by BranchName, ScriptName
                                order by [XMLColumn].value('count(//data)', 'int')
                               ) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by BranchName, ScriptName) as cnt
      from temp t
     ) t
group by BranchName, ScriptName;
```

Comment: I edited my question to reflect why I haven't accepted this as the answer (since it produces multiple rows for each branch that do not allow for distinguishing between the developers producing the maximum and minimum).